# Java Records and Lombok annotation - IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-lombok-plugin, java-14, java-record

Just trying a hands-on the [java.lang.Record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html). I have gone through the documentation and the [JEP-359](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) for some understanding. So upon reading about the implicit declaration of the constructor I thought of mixing it up with an existing code generation library - Lombok!

Now what I've ended up creating as a minimal reproducible example is this record

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
public record Java(String version) {
}
```

which when compiled using IntelliJ successfully produces the class file which looks like

```
public final class Java extends java.lang.Record {
    private final java.lang.String version;
    public Java(java.lang.String version) { /* compiled code */ }
    ... rest of the compiled code
}
```

Note that the constructor for the `.class` file is just what I would have expected in the two worlds independently as well. But, further trying to create an instance of this record fails during compilation in IntelliJ :

```
public class MixOfWorlds {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Java("14").version()); // cannot resolve constructor
    }
}
```

I would create a further simpler example to perform the compilation with `javac` and execution with `java` tools. I am still looking for an answer if this is a possible expected behavior that could occur because of something I might have overlooked?

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP (Community Edition)
Build #IC-201.6487.11, built on March 18, 2020 
Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b765.15 x86_64 
macOS 10.14.6
```

This is how it reflects in IntelliJ for both the cases - with and without the `@AllArgsConstructor`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sufficient code to reproduce `@AllArgsConstructor
public record Java(String version, boolean preview) {
    public Java(String version) {
        this(version, true);
    }
}`

Comment: Lombok does not support records yet, but it's planned: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2356. Until then, weird things may happen.

Comment: BTW: What exactly are you trying to achieve? An `AllArgsConstructor` on a record makes no sense, because javac would generate one anyway.

Comment: @JanRieke wasn't really trying to achieve anything from the shared code, it was purely experimental and the doubt is around the `.class` generated with appropriate constructor and still not being able to create an instance of the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on this and with some help online from the IntelliJ developers, I had tried the following steps to resolve this --

1. I was assured that it looks more about `javac-lombok` interaction and was not connected to IDE.
2. I could actually gain the confidence to try running the code despite the highlighted error(which looks like a compile-time error) and it successfully executed to print **"14"** as expected.
3. I can confirm that after ***disabling the "Lombok Plugin"*** installed in the IDE, the highlighted error disappears.

[image]

***Note***: The second step was *with the plugin installed*. So in short, it just happens that the plugin gets to highlight the code as if it wouldn't compile, but the actual execution is handled by IntelliJ properly. (Kudos!)

***Edit***: With the [`1.8.20` release](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2681#issuecomment-812288829), Lombok prevents a `record` to be annotated with an `AllArgsConstructor` any more. You can access the official changelog [here](https://projectlombok.org/changelog).